# portrait page with section title, and "landscaped longtable"

Tags: longtable, landscape, section-titles, pdflscape

I have the following landscaped longtable under a section:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}

\section{Landscaped longtable issues}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{cccc}
\caption{Observations}\label{tab:X}\\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
type & type & unit & an incredibly wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide source\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ (\emph{continued from previous page})} \\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
type & type & unit & an incredibly wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide source\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{r}%
{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

Asian 1 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 2 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 3 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 4 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 5 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 6 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 7 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 8 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 9 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 10 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 11 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 12 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 13 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 14 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 15 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 16 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 17 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 18 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 19 & Yellow & X & R\\
Asian 20 & Yellow & X & R\\
American 1 & Red & Y & R\\
American 2 & Red & Y & R\\
American 3 & Red & Y & R\\
American 4 & Red & Y & R\\
American 5 & Red & Y & R\\
American 6 & Red & Y & R\\
American 7 & Red & Y & R\\
American 8 & Red & Y & R\\
American 9 & Red & Y & R\\
American 10 & Red & Y & R\\
American 11 & Red & Y & R\\
American 12 & Red & Y & R\\
American 13 & Red & Y & R\\
American 14 & Red & Y & R\\
American 15 & Red & Y & R\\
American 16 & Red & Y & R\\
American 17 & Red & Y & R\\
American 18 & Red & Y & R\\
American 19 & Red & Y & R\\
American 20 & Red & Y & R\\
& & &\\
\cdashline{1-3}
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{\textbf{Mean type}} & Z &\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{(standard deviation)} & (SD) &\\

\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

as you see the landscape environment breaks the page right after the section title. Is it possible to have the landscaped longtable on the first page, right after the section title, while keeping the whole page in portrait orientation (i.e. I just want the longtable rotated, nothing else)? I know this is an old question, but I couldn't really find an elegant solution to the problem so far, and just wanted to hear from the community.............. cheers!

Comment: No, it is not possible. Landscape pages always start new page. One way is use `sideways` defined in `rotating˙ package, hoewer it can be only on one page. Does this section contain only table?

Comment: **@Zarko**: it contains a "true longtable", i.e., the longtable spans over multiple pages.............

Comment: **@Zarko**: I'll update the MWE (as soon as I find some time) with a multipage longtable. For better illustration..............

Comment: **@Zarko**: longtable in MWE has been updated..............

Comment: From typographical point of view have a mix of portrait and landscape page is not appealing. Beside this, the width of table had to bi smaller from text height, this amount may cast doubt on the eligibility of necessity of landscape oriented table. Width of table generated by your MWE doesn't show any need to have longtable in landscape pages ...

Comment: Please, make your table example more realistic, what you like to have. At least in one row insert (dummy) text, example images provided by `graphic` package , units etc, which are more similar to real table.

Comment: **@Zarko**: of course the table width should be larger than the portrait mode page width to justify a landscape orientation. I just didn't add more columns to the table to show that there is indeed a blank space after the section title, regardless of how wide the table is, but I can easily expand the table width if that's relevant..............

Comment: **@Zarko**: longtable in MWE has been again updated and should now be wide enough to justify its landscape orientation..............

Comment: An example table with example contents closer to the actual contents might be more useful here. Probably, there is a way to make the table fit onto a portrait oriented page? With the current quite "artificial" example, this is hard to tell.

Comment: @leandriis, I agree with you. For example, an *an incredibly wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide source* consisting from natural worts can be easy writed in more lines (using `p{...}˙columns, or even better use `xltabular` table environment ...

Answer (score 0):

One can overlap the rotated section heading and the longtable, just be careful not to actually overlap them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\setbox\tempbox=\vbox{\section{Landscaped longtable issues}}

\begin{landscape}
\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\smash{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{-90}{\usebox\tempbox}}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{longtable}[l]{cccc}
\caption{Observations}\label{tab:X}\\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
type & type & unit & source\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ (\emph{continued from previous page})} \\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
unit & unit & unit & unit\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{r}%
{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

Asian & Yellow & X & R\\
American & Red & Y & R\\
& & &\\
\cdashline{1-3}
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{\textbf{Mean type}} & Z &\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{(standard deviation)} & (SD) &\\

\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: **@John**: what about hyperlinks to the section caption? To they point appropriately?..............

Comment: **@John**: nevermind, I'll answer that question myself and come back to you, if I have further questions or comments..............

Comment: **@John**: not sure yet how document-class-independent your proposed solution is. Hyperlink to Section looks fine for now. Hyperlink to Table looks bad.............. took the liberty to update your code with the hyperlinked cross-references.............. also switched to lscape (looks more consistent I think) and expanded the number of lines in the longtable for a true representation of a multipage longtable in landscape mode.............. –

Comment: **@Jonh**: do you think it is possible to have the hyperlink to the "landscaped longtable" pointing to the latter's caption? Would that be possible?..............

Comment: You can use `\hyperlink{foo}{\ref*{tab:X}}` to link to `\hypertarget{foo}{}`.  The trouble is putting a `\hypertarget` to the right of a longtable.

Answer (score 0):

From provided MWE is hard to figured out, how the real table should looks. This may seems irrelevant to you, but we are unable to suggest you some, a wee bit different approach in table design, which will give better table format and also may make use of `landscape` pages unnecessary:

One possible solution can consider:

- portrait page orientation with extend text width with `adjustwidth` macro defined in the `changepage` table
- use `xltabular` table with modified `` column type in the last column
- use of rules from the `booktabs` package
- added additional vertical spaces around cells contents by use of the `makecellgaped` macro defined in the `makecell` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}                       % new added
\usepackage{arydshln,
            booktabs, makecell, xltabular}  % new, added
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} %  added
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, label font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\section{A wide table present in the portrait page}

    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} ccc L @{}}
    \caption{Observations}
    \label{tab:X}                                               \\
    \toprule
\thead[b]{A\\ type}
    &   \thead[b]{B\\ type}
        & \thead[b]{C\\ unit}
            & \thead[b]{D\\ some description of column content} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Observations 
               (\emph{continued from previous page})}   \\
    \toprule
\thead[b]{A\\ type}
    &   \thead[b]{B\\ type}
        & \thead[b]{C\\ unit}
            & \thead[b]{D\\ some description of column content} \\ 
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\small(\emph{continued on next page})}   \\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%%%%    table body
Asian 1     & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 2     & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 3     & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 4     & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 5     & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 6     & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 7     & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 8     & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 9     & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 10    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 11    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 12    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 13    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 14    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 15    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 16    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 17    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 18    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 19    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
Asian 20    & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
American 1  & Yellow    & X & \lipsum[66] \\
American 2  &  Yellow   & X & \lipsum[66] \\
\end{xltabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: prva stran]

[image: druga in tretja stran]

(red lines indicate page layout)

It is possible to make some more tweaks of table design if the (imitation) of the real table contents would be known. For example, third column if contain units, can bi of `s` type defined in `siunitx` package, used can be smaller font size, for example `\small` etc. Anyway, to my opinion suggested solution looks better better than as your intended table format.